# How to configure folder rights to execute the command

Tags: php, windows, symfony, exec, rights

Since several month, i m trying to user exec command in order to launch a file import in a business management application.
The software name is EBP, we must use a .exe file to do import.
Here is the command

```
"C:\\Program Files\\EBP\\Invoicing11.0FRFR40\\EBP.Invoicing.Application.exe"
/Gui=false;"C:\INTERFACES_TEST\ALKOR\logs\20230307112630.txt " /Database="C:\Users\Public\ABPOST_TEST.ebp";USR;PASSWORD
/Import="C:\INTERFACES_TEST\ALKOR\todo\230306151623_CDE_A638-00005912.csv";SaleOrders;SDK_ImportAlkorShop
```

If i launch it in a terminal, it works.
I would like to launch it with PHP. So in Symfony, i add a controller to do the import, in this controller i add the following lines:

```
$commande = escapeshellarg($this->ebpImportExecutable)
    . ' /Gui=false;' . escapeshellarg($this->urlImportArkor.'logs\\'.date('YmdHis').'.txt" ')
    . ' /Database=' . escapeshellarg($this->database).';USR;PASSWORD'
    . ' /Import=' . escapeshellarg($this->urlImportArkor . 'todo\\' . $nomdufichier) . ';SaleOrders;SDK_ImportAlkorShop';
//echo $commande;exit();

exec($commande, $output, $retCode);
```

With Postman i tryed to to the import, the output of the exec command is an empty array.

In the Windows Application Log, i found the following error:

```
Application : EBP.Invoicing.Application.exe Version du Framework : v4.0.30319 
Description : le processus a été arrêté en raison d'une exception non gérée. 
Informations sur l'exception : System.ArgumentException à System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(System.String[], Boolean) 
    à System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlActions, System.String[], Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) 
    à System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess, System.String) 
    à System.Environment.InternalGetFolderPath(SpecialFolder, SpecialFolderOption, Boolean) 
    à EBP.Framework.Common.FoldersHelper+<>c.<.cctor>b__11_5() 
    à System.Lazy`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].CreateValue() 
    à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() 
    à System.Lazy`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].get_Value() 
    à EBP.Framework.Common.FoldersHelper+<>c.<.cctor>b__11_4() 
    à System.Lazy`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].CreateValue() 
    à System.Lazy`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].LazyInitValue() 
    à EBP.Framework.Common.Log.LogHelper.GetIsLoggingEnabled() 
    à EBP.Framework.Common.Log.LogHelper.get_IsLoggingEnabled() 
    à EBP.Framework.Common.Log.LogHelper.Log(EBP.Framework.Common.Interfaces.Host.ISharedHostedApplication, Int16, System.Exception) 
    à EBP.Framework.Windows.Host.WinHost.CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(System.Object, System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) 
Informations sur l'exception : System.TypeInitializationException 
    à 8xM=.BRQ=.TxQ=() à 8xM=.BRQ=.OBQ=() à EBP.Framework.BusinessLogic.Host.DataHostedApplication.Initialize(Boolean) 
    à EBP.Framework.Windows.Host.WinHostedApplication.Initialize(Boolean) 
    à EBP.Invoicing.Application.HostedApplication.Initialize(Boolean) 
    à EBP.Framework.Common.Host.HostBase.InitializeApplication(EBP.Framework.Common.Interfaces.Host.ISharedHostedApplication, Boolean) 
    à EBP.Framework.Windows.Host.WinHost.InitializeApplication(EBP.Framework.Common.Interfaces.Host.ISharedHostedApplication, Boolean) 
    à EBP.Framework.Common.Host.HostBase.Run(EBP.Framework.Common.Host.IHostedApplication, Boolean, System.String[]) 
    à EBP.Invoicing.Application.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

There seems to be a permission error.
Does anybody have an idea ?
I tryed shell_exec and system command. i ve got the same issue.
Should i modify folder permission ?

Thank you

Comment: If you display `$output` or `$retCode` with `var_dump()`, everything is empty...?

Comment: $output is an empty array, $retCode return int(255)

Comment: I don't know if we can really help you here because you would have to know if it is indeed linked to a legal problem on the file. But what file...? `C:\INTERFACES_TEST\ALKOR\logs\` or `C:\INTERFACES_TEST\ALKOR\todo\`...? Because the error would come that the Apache or PHP user (I don't know which one launches the command) does not have the rights to write in these folders...? While he has the right to run the executable.

Comment: I added the computer to our new domain.
I always log in to Windows with the local admin account.
When I try to import files from the directory, the files are deleted after import by the PHP program. But I still get the same error with the application not importing the data.